# Biggest (centered) polydisc of holomorphy

Tags: several-complex-variables

I have trouble defining the biggest centered polydisc of holomorphy (where I can apply cauchy's inequality) of a multivariate complex holomorphic function. As an example, suppose a function of 2 variables with 3 poles:

$$f(z_1,z_2) = \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{z_1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{z_2}{2}\right)\left(1-z_1z_2\right)}$$

The function has singularities:

- On $\left\{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb C^2:\, z_1 = 2\right\}$
- On $\left\{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb C^2:\, z_2 = 2\right\}$
- On $\left\{(z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb C^2:\, z_1 = \frac{1}{z_2}\right\}$

I have two questions:

- For each of the three singularities, if only this one occured, what would be the polyradius of the biggest polydisc of holomorphy ?
- What is the polyradius of the biggest polydisc of holomorphy for the full function ?

Comment: Why do you believe there is such a thing as the biggest polydisk of holomorphy???

Comment: Well, I do not know. Assuming the function is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the origin, there should be a polydisc centered at the origin that is contained in this neighbourhood, no ?

Comment: yes of course. I don't see what that has to do with a biggest polydisk. A _maximal_ polydisk, certainly.

Comment: I never claimed that my terminology was the good one. If you prefer to call that a *maximal* polydisc, be my gest, as long as we have the same object in mind ;) However google searchs on *maximal polydisk* instead of *biggest polydisc* still doesnt return anything relevant to my question...

Comment: ??? The difference between "biggest" and "maximal" is perfectly standard; when I say that although I don't see where there should be a biggest polydisk but there may well be a maximal one that's not because I "prefer to call" it that. I don't see what a google search has to do with this. "as long as we have te same object in mind": Huh? **If** you have the standard definition in mind when you say "biggest polydisk" then what you have in mind is definitely not the same as what one means by "maximal polydisk".

Comment: The problem is the following to me: I am not skilled enough to defined properly the maximum and/or biggest polydisc. What i wanted was the disc of polyradius $r_1,r_2$ that had the biggest polyradius possible, say w.r.t a given norm in $L2(R^2)$. What do you call a 'maximal' polydisc ?

Comment: Btw you just *did* this thing you've been insisting you're unable to do. The sentence "What I wanted..." is a perfectly precise and clear statement of what you meant by "largest". (yes, there certainly will be largest polydiscs in that sense)

Comment: Thanks for helping me clearing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks for the largest polydisk contained in a certain set, as though the existence of a largest polydisk was clear. It's been commented that the existence of a largest polydisk is not at all clear to at least one reader, while of course a *maximal* polydisk is much more plausible. When the OP replies "if you prefer to call [largest] [maximal] be my guest" it seems like an example clarifying the difference may be a good idea.
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathcal R}$
Say $D=\{(x,y):x,y\ge0,xy\le1\}$. Say a *rectangle* is a set of the form $[a,b]\times[c,d]$, let $\R$ be the set of all rectangles contained in $D$, and let $R_0=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Then $R_0$ is not the largest element of $\R$, because for example if $R_1=[0,2]\times[0,1/2]$ then $R_1\in\R$ but $R_1\not\subset R_0$.

But $R_0$ *is* a maximal element of $\R$; this means that, as you can easily verify, if $R_1\in\R$ and $R_0\subset R_1$ then $R_0=R_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the definition of 'maximal' that you used. Indeed, it was very unclear to me. Both of these difinitions will work out for my initial problem: behind this question, i want to show that i can apply Cauchy's inequality with radii > 1 for certain functions, but i have trouble defining, from the set of singularities, what are the biggest (and/or maximal) radii that i can use. I hope i'm clearer.